# Most efficient way to rapidly capture raw images with Camera2API

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I've been modifying the Camera2Raw sample code (https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Raw). I'm attempting to get "raw video" by just taking a series of raw DNG images successively. Preferably, at some defined framerate. (So far, I've modified the app to not take JPEGs, and I've added a user interface to input manual exposure - no more auto exposure settings.)

The way the code handles the "take picture" button is like this:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.picture: {

                int i = 0;
                while(i<48){
                    takePicture();
                    i++;
                }

               //default behavior is to just  take one picture:
               //takePicture();
                break;
            }
```

As you can see, I've modified it to take 48 "frames" by putting takePicture() in a while loop. And... this does actually kind of work! When I put the frames into my video editor, the result is a roughly 30 fps video. However, there are frequent stutters, and the app doesn't actually take exactly 48 frames.

Ok, so just calling takePicture() in succession is probably not the best way of doing this. I'm thinking I'm going to want something like a setRepeatingRequest. In takePicture() itself, the final line is

```
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mPreCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

I've replaced the `.capture` with `.setRepeatingRequest`, but the app still behaves the same, and takes only one picture.

For what it's worth, my Pixel 6 Pro reports `[w:4080, h:3072, format:RAW_SENSOR(32), min_duration:33333333, stall:0]` in it's StreamConfiguration outputs. If I'm interpreting that correctly, it tells us that at least in theory, the device can take raw, 4080 x 3072 images at roughly 30 fps. I'd be happy with even 24 fps - but it needs to be a steady framerate for it to be a usable video.

To be clear, my desired output is simply a folder of DNG images, i.e. a cinemaDNG.

And yes, at some point I'm going to want an actual start/stop recording button, not just a "take X frames"  button, this is just a proof of concept for now.

I guess my question really just boils down to "how do I properly use a setRepeatingRequest," but I welcome any further commentary and advice regarding raw still/video capture in general.